# How to Customize Bootstrap 4

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I need to use just some parts of bootstrap 4, not all of that. and I want to use my customize bootstrap in my wordpress theme and sell it on Themeforest store or somewhere, I dont want to use bootstrap.js and many parts of bootstrap.css.

I want to use these items ...

- reset css
- Print media styles
- Grid system
- Responsive utilities
- Navbar
- Breadcrumbs
- Responsive embed

can I copy/paste my ideal parts of bootstrap css?
can I use just these parts of bootstrap 4 ?
can I sell my theme with this CSS file?
its ok to copy and change some part of this files?
which license I need to use in my theme?

my question is more about licenses...

Comment: Bootstrap is an open src project it has an MIT license which means you can do whatever you want to do with that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/about/license/

Read the first couple Lines. Bootstrap has an MIT open source license. you can find more on that here. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT_License

You can copy and paste the code that you want however you must keep the Copyright title intact for the pieces that you use from bootstrap.

Comment: can i copy/paste these codes in my custom style.css file with bootstrap license? or should in separate files? style.css + bootstrap.css

Comment: you can "Use Bootstrap in packages or distributions that you create", according to that first link. yes you can put the code in your style.css file, but the answer to your question is personal preference. I don't think there are legal ramifications to code organization. *disclaimer I am not a lawyer

Answer (score -1):

You could just override bootstrap my adding your own class on top of bootstrap's class

```
.row.shaheparsRow {
    padding: 0
}
```